# SQL Server How to get NULL when its not match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get NULL when it's not match with the query ....

this is how my table look like

[image]

[image]

And here is my t-sql

```
SELECT Product.ProductId,
       Product.ProductName,
       Product.ProductPrice,
       Product.ProductQuantity,
       property.PropertyId,
       ProductUnderCategory.SubCategoryId,
       SubCategory.SubCategoryName,
       EE.propertyname AS eee,
       ProductProperties.PropertyValue
FROM Product
JOIN ProductProperties ON Product.ProductId = ProductProperties.ProductId
JOIN property ON property.PropertyId = ProductProperties.PropertyId,
     property AS EE
JOIN CategoryProperty ON EE.PropertyId = CategoryProperty.PropertyId,
     SubCategory
JOIN ProductUnderCategory ON SubCategory.SubCategoryId = ProductUnderCategory.SubCategoryId
WHERE Product.ProductId = 10
    AND ProductUnderCategory.ProductId = 10
    AND CategoryProperty.SubCategoryId = ProductUnderCategory.SubCategoryId
```

Comment: Check an answer, It should work for you.

Comment: How can your query result show a value if there isn't a value to show? What do you mean "because contents has no value", the value looks to be "2018" or "for shave".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expression to check If `EE.propertyname = 'Contents'` then use `NULL` as value, otherwise use `ProperyValue` in following:

```
SELECT Product.ProductId,
       Product.ProductName,
       Product.ProductPrice,
       Product.ProductQuantity,
       property.PropertyId,
       ProductUnderCategory.SubCategoryId,
       SubCategory.SubCategoryName,
       EE.propertyname AS eee,
       CASE WHEN EE.propertyname = 'Contents' THEN NULL 
            ELSE ProductProperties.PropertyValue 
       END as PropertyValue 
FROM Product
JOIN ProductProperties ON Product.ProductId = ProductProperties.ProductId
JOIN property ON property.PropertyId = ProductProperties.PropertyId,
     property AS EE
JOIN CategoryProperty ON EE.PropertyId = CategoryProperty.PropertyId,
     SubCategory
JOIN ProductUnderCategory ON SubCategory.SubCategoryId = ProductUnderCategory.SubCategoryId
WHERE Product.ProductId = 10
    AND ProductUnderCategory.ProductId = 10
    AND CategoryProperty.SubCategoryId = ProductUnderCategory.SubCategoryId
```